# Requests to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ return a 501 HTTPS

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to build a mod for my Minecraft server in 1.7.10, but when I tried to execute `./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace`, I got the error below.

I went to forums to see if other people had experienced this, and some had but my research did not explain how to modify the code to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. Any advice is appreciated.

````
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'Client (Forge)'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:common:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:jobs:3.5.300-v20130429-1813
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:3.5.100-v20130422-1538
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:common.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:preferences.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:registry:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:registry.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core.runtime:compatibility:[3.1.0,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core.runtime:compatibility.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/runtime/compatibility/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/runtime/compatibility/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:expressions:[3.1.0,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:expressions.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/expressions/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/expressions/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:filesystem:[1.0.0,2.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:filesystem.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/filesystem/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/filesystem/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse:osgi:[3.7.0,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse:osgi.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/osgi/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/osgi/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:common:[3.6.100,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:common.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:jobs:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:jobs.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/jobs/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/jobs/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:registry:[3.4.0,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:registry.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:[3.4.0,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:preferences.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:contenttype:[3.3.0,4.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:contenttype.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/contenttype/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/contenttype/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
       > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:app:[1.0.0,2.0.0).
         Required by:
             :Client (Forge):unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
          > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:app.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/app/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/app/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED```
````

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this a few months ago [here](https://gist.github.com/Arzio/848b8375c4c2ff828d5a7470ac1866b6)

```java
// The comments with [HTTPS FIX] tag refers to the parts that fixes the issue.

buildscript {
    repositories {

        // [HTTPS FIX] Replace mavenCentral() with the code block below
        maven {
            url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" 
        }

        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
        maven {
            name = "sonatype"
            url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

// [HTTPS FIX] Add the code block below
allprojects {
    repositories {
        all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
            if (repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository){
                if (repo.url.toString().startsWith("http://repo1.maven.org/maven2")) {
                    repo.url = repo.url.toString().replace("http://", "https://")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'forge'

version = "1.0"
group= "com.yourname.modid" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = "modid"

minecraft {
    version = "1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10"
    runDir = "eclipse"
}

dependencies {

}

processResources
{
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'
                
        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }
        
    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file, replace `http://repo1.maven.org` with `https://repo1.maven.org`.

Comment: That url doesn't appear anywhere in the build.gradle that ships with minecraft forge.

Comment: @RyanBemrose I suspect the OP added it, based on the errors in the question.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I found this question via websearch after encountering exactly the same error with an unmodified Forge download. I think Forge downloads some configuration on the backend that redirects to maven.org, but I don't know enough gradle to understand what's happening. Unfortunately, this is an old version of Forge which is out of support, and they're locking any forum thread that asks for help.